# Storing C++ strings in STL set

Tags: c++, string, stl, set

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    set<string> s;

    s.insert("hi");

    set<string>::iterator it = s.find("hi");

    if (it == s.end()) {
        cout << "Matched." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Not matched." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output says Not matched.

I want to store a set of unique strings. But the find() in set doesn't find the strings I have inserted already. Does the default less comparator object not work on strings? If not, then how do I assign the correct comparator object for strings?

Comment: Instead of if (it == s.end()) use  if (it != s.end()) , as the find will return a an iterator to the first element in the range that compares equal to val ("hi"), if no elements match, the function returns last (s.end()).

Comment: Incidentally, if you just need to check if an element is present the `count` method is way less verbose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably misunderstood how [find()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) function works. If its return value is equal to s.end(), it does not mean that it's matched. On the contrary, it means that the string you are looking for could not be found until the end iterator of the set was reached.

So you should reverse the if statement as given below.

```
if (it == s.end()) {
    cout << "Matched." << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Not matched." << endl;
}
```

to

```
if (it != s.end()) {
    cout << "Matched." << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Not matched." << endl;
}
```

Comment: @siri No problem. If you are satisfied with the answers provided so far, remember to pick one of them as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` condition is opposite, it should be

```
if (it != s.end()) {
       ~~
    cout << "Matched." << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Not matched." << endl;
}
```

See [`std::set::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) :

> Return value
>
> Iterator to an element with key equivalent to key. If no such element
>   is found, past-the-end (see `end()`) iterator is returned.

Answer (score 2):

If `find("hi")` is equal to `s.end()` it does not mean that it's matched. On the contrary, it means that the string you are looking for could not be found until the end iterator of the set was reached.